# ASP.NET MVC2 - specific fields in form pass via a specific object?

Tags: asp.net, post, asp.net-mvc-2, formcollection

In database I have Contacts table:

```
ContactID (int)
FirstName (varchar)
LastName (varchar)
...
XmlFields (xml) // This field is xml type
```

To create a new contact, I created two classes - one for regular fields and other to display fields from `XmlFields` field.

In Controller, I have following:

```
public ActionResult Create(Contact contact, FormCollection collection)
...
```

Regular field I catch with `contact` object and those that need to be stored as xml in `XmlFields` I try to catch with `collection` object. Problem is that  `collection` object catches all fields, so I wonder if it is possible to isolate xml fields when posting to a specific object so that I can easily manipulate with them.
I need this in separated objects because these xml fields are going to be generated dynamically and will be different for every user.

Thanks in advance,
Ile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate fields like:

```
public ActionResult Create(int ContactID, string FirstName)
```

And pass the raw data to the XML...  There isn't any automatic way for MVC to know where to push what data to, unless you consider creating a custom model binder: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/09/08/CustomModelBinderMoreUIValidationASPNETMVC.aspx which is another valid option.

HTH.