# nested linq-to-sql queries

Tags: linq-to-sql, nested

```
var result = (
    from contact in db.Contacts                             
    join user in db.Users on contact.CreatedByUserID equals user.UserID
    orderby contact.ContactID descending
    select new ContactListView
    {
        ContactID = contact.ContactID,
        FirstName = contact.FirstName,
        LastName = contact.LastName,
        Company = (
            from field in contact.XmlFields.Descendants("Company")
            select field.Value).SingleOrDefault().ToString()
    }).Take(10);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744054/asp-net-mvc2-specific-fields-in-form-pass-via-a-specific-object) I described how my database tables look like. So, `contacts` table has one field that is `xml` type. In that field is stored Company filename and I need to read it. I tried it using this way:

```
Company = (
    from field in contact.XmlFields.Descendants("Company")
    select field.Value).SingleOrDefault().ToString()
```

but I get following error:

> Member access 'System.String Value' of
>   'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' not legal
>   on type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement].

Any solution for this?

Thanks in advance,
Ile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that LINQ to SQL is trying to transform the `Descendants` extension method and `XElement.Value` to SQL, but it of course fails. You will have to do this last transformation with LINQ to Objects. This would work:

```
var temp = (
    from contact in db.Contacts                             
    join user in db.Users on contact.CreatedByUserID equals user.UserID
    orderby contact.ContactID descending
    select new
    {
        contact.ContactID, contact.FirstName, contact.LastName, contact.XmlFields
    })
    .Take(10);

var tempArray = temp.ToArray();

IEnumerable<ContactListView> result =
    from contact in tempArray
    let company =
        (from field in contact.XmlFields.Descendants("Company")
         select field.Value).SingleOrDefault()
    select new ContactListView()
    {
        ContactID = contact.ContactID,
        FirstName = contact.FirstName,
        LastName = contact.LastName,
        Company = company == null ? null : company.ToString()
    }).Take(10);
```

Comment: yes, this is it. I'd never figure it out alone :) Although, it's not really practical solution, but it's important that it works. Thanks ;)